# C# program to count and notifiy users of Unsent Outbox message from Outlook

Tags: c#

Good day everyone,
i am new to C# and have a project that i need to find a way to count all unsent messages in the Outlook Outbox and notify the user as such that they are not sent

i found this online but not sure where to go from here to modify for outbox

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox =
        this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder          

        Outlook.Items unreadItems = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");

    MessageBox.Show(
        string.Format("Unread items in Inbox = {0}", unreadItems.Count));
}
```

any guideance is helpful

I have tried this code  but doesnt seem to work

```
using System;`your text`
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

// Define the time threshold for identifying stuck emails
TimeSpan threshold = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

// Retrieve the current user's email address
string currentUserEmail = string.Empty;

try
{
    WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    string userPrincipalName = windowsIdentity.Name;
    currentUserEmail = userPrincipalName.Substring(userPrincipalName.IndexOf("@") + 1);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle any exception when retrieving the user's email address
    Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving current user's email: " + ex.Message);
}

// Create the Outlook application and retrieve the Outbox folder
    Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder outboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
    Outlook.Items items = outboxFolder.Items;

// Iterate through the emails in the Outbox folder and check for stuck emails
foreach (Outlook.MailItem email in items)
{
    if (DateTime.Now - email.SentOn > threshold)
    {
        // Email is stuck, send alert to the current user's email address
        try
        {
            using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("stmpclient"))
            {
                using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
                {
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("sender_email");
                    mail.To.Add(currentUserEmail);
                    mail.Subject = "Stuck Email Alert";
                    mail.Body = "One or more emails are stuck in the Outlook Outbox. Please take     necessary action.";    

                    smtpClient.Send(mail);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle any exception when sending the alert
            Console.WriteLine("Error sending alert email: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SOe. Please check [help] and [faq]. More the point, make **specific questions** explaining an **specificic problem** you have encountered, including your code and both expected and actual behavior. "I do not know how to do my work" posts does not fit this site.

Comment: "I have tried this code but doesnt seem to work" - what is not working?